# how to display some part of html data in the jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please help me, I have tried a lot of search but useless.

```
<div class="articleWraper">
                <div id="demo2">
<?php
$sSql='SELECT * FROM tbl_images';
$result=mysql_query($sSql);
?>
  <ul id="slider3">
  <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
   <li class="panel1">
    <div class="caption-bottom"><?php echo $row['line1_desc'];?><br/><?php echo $row['line2_desc'];?></div>
    <img src="../propertyImages/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" /><br />
   </li>
   <?php }?>
  </ul>
 </div>
        <div class="mpCaptionRow">
                        <input id="createLink" class="createLink" type="submit" name="submit" value="Yes, I'm Interested" />
                    </div>
            </div>
```

The above code is for a button and a manual slider. The slider contains pictures and a panel for picture description which are getting from database. I want when the user clicks on button and jQuery dialog appears then some part of description containing slider panel will be show in the jQuery dialog. My jQuery dialog code is as follows:

```
    <head>
            <link href="Content/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="Content/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/page.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/anythingslider.css" />

            <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/jquery.anythingslider.fx.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/demo.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqxmaskedinput.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#createLink").click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $("#mpDialog").dialog(
                            {
                                title: "I want to be a future homeowner",
                                width: 520,
                                modal: true,
                                position: {
                                    at: "top",
                                    my: "bottom",
                                    of: "#createLink"
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    });
                    $("#mpDialog").hide();
        });

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="dialogSec" id="mpDialog">
                <form id="createProductForm" name="myForm" action="futureHomeowner.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div id="productDetails">
                        <div id="basicInfo">
                            <p style="text-align: center">Hey Mike and Juan<br />
                                I am interested in learning more about the property at:
    <br />

**I want the panel description here**

    <br /> 
    and specifically how your program works to allow me to become a homeowner.</p>
                                <div class="fieldControl">
                                <label style="margin-right: 25px">First Name </label>
                                <input id="fname" type="text" class="textBox" name="fname" style="width: 350px" />
                                <div id="fname_error"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldControl">
                                <label style="margin-right: 25px">Last Name </label>
                                <input id="lname" type="text" class="textBox" name="lname" style="width: 350px" />
                                <div id="lname_error"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldControl">
                                <label>Email Address </label>
                                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="textBox" style="width: 350px" />
                                <div id="email_error"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldControl">
                                <label>Phone No. </label>
                                <input id="phoneNo" type="text" name="phoneNo" class="textBox" style="width: 350px" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="fieldControl">
                            <p>Please answer the questions below and we will be in touch.</p>
                                <p style="text-align: left;"><b>What is the best time to call you to discuss?</b></p>
                                From <input id="timeformat1" name="timeFrom" type="text" class="textBox" style="width: 205px" placeholder="Time from" /> To <input id="timeformat2" placeholder="Time to" name="timeTo" type="text" class="textBox" style="width: 205px" />
                                <p style="text-align: left;"><b>Also, do you have any other comments?</b></p>
                                <textarea name="comments" style="width: 489px" class="textBox" placeholder="Write your comments..."></textarea>
                                </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearSection"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttonsRow">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button1" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to do from another website?  I don't really understand what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @chockleyc yes I have see http://www.kinmangroup.com/ login with username: qaser_shah2000@yahoo.com and pass: qaser when you logged in then click on properties currently available link from menu you will see the page having a slider and a button saying "Yes, I'm interested" when user click on this button a form appears and at the top of form there is a para. I want the some part of the text in third line from the slider panel.